# LDAP: entries for services?

Tags: ldap, authorization, apache-ds

(Apologies if I've got the terminology wrong, I'm fairly new to LDAP)

I am setting up a local LDAP server (Apache Directory Server) with the following structure:

```
o={my organization name} [objectClass=organization]
  ou=groups [objectClass=organizationalUnit]
    cn=someGroup [objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames]
    cn=otherGroup [objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames]
    ...
  ou=users [objectClass=organizationalUnit]
    cn=user1 [objectClass=inetOrgPerson]
    cn=user2 [objectClass=inetOrgPerson]
    cn=user3 [objectClass=inetOrgPerson]
    ...
```

I also set up some [basic authorization according to the manual](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/32-basic-authorization.html).

Everything works great.

Now I have an issue. I have another server running Atlassian Crowd that needs access to this LDAP, and I would like to give that service its own LDAP authorization entry, to partition access rights. But it's not a *user*, it's a *service*.

**What objectClass is used for service identities?**

(and as a newbie to LDAP, how do you find out that groupOfUniqueNames is used for groups, inetOrgPerson is used for user entries? That seems to be the norm.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What objectClass is used for service identities?

Whatever you want, really.  In order for Crowd (or anything else) to
authenticate, you need a distinguished name somewhere in your tree and
it needs to have a `userPassword` attribute.

If you look at your schema (if you're using OpenLDAP, that's usually
`/etc/openldap/schema`), you can find objectClasses that meet this
criteria.

The simplest is probably the `person` object class, the definition for
which looks like this:

```
objectclass ( 2.5.6.6 NAME 'person'
        DESC 'RFC2256: a person'
        SUP top STRUCTURAL
        MUST ( sn $ cn )
        MAY ( userPassword $ telephoneNumber $ seeAlso $ description ) )
```

That says that it requires the `sn` and `cn` attributes, and may
optionally have a `userPassword` attribute (as well as a few others).
So maybe you would add an entry like this:

```
dn: cn=crowd,ou=serviceAccounts, o=myOrganization
objectClass: person
cn: crowd
sn: Service Account
description: Service account for Crowd access to LDAP
userPassword: {SSHA}MZO/eoDUg/nFJDAZBvawCRYIxSeQUm3U
```

This presumes that you have a `serviceAccounts` OU where you will
place this sort of thing, which is probably a good idea (because this
clearly separates service accounts from user accounts).

Crowd would authenticate as
`cn=crowd,ou=serviceAccountrs,o=myOrganization`, and you would need to
configure your LDAP directory to give this DN the appopriate access
permissions.

Comment: You could of course create a custom object class for this if you wanted, but I don't think that's the best course of action.

Comment: re: serviceAccounts -- yeah, I was thinking along those lines. Thanks for your help, it provides some enlightenment.

Answer (score 8):

RFC 2256 / RFC 4519 recommends `objectClass: applicationProcess` for this sort of thing:

> The 'applicationProcess' object class definition is the basis of an 
>   entry that represents an application executing in a computer system.

Relevant attributes: `cn` (required), `seeAlso`, `ou`, `l`, and `description` (optional).

One advantage of using `cn` instead of `uid` for the RDN is that service accounts won't be mistakenly matched as user accounts if you're using something like `ldap_filter: (uid=%U)` as the user lookup query.

Answer (score 6):

I use object classes `account` (structural) and `simpleSecurityObject` (auxiliary) for service accounts. This way the service account has a `uid` and a `userPassword`, both of which are good to have when doing authentication and authorization.

```
dn: uid=kerberos,ou=services,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: account
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: top
uid: kerberos
userPassword: {SSHA}xxxxxxxxxx
```